# Using Python to write a CSV file with delimiter

Tags: python, csv

I'm new to programming, and also to this site, so my apologies in advance for anything silly or "newbish" I may say or ask.

I'm currently trying to write a script in python that will take a list of items and write them into a csv file, among other things. Each item in the list is really a list of two strings, if that makes sense. In essence, the format is [[Google, http://google.com], [BBC, http://bbc.co.uk]], but with different values of course.

Within the CSV, I want this to show up as the first item of each list in the first column and the second item of each list in the second column.

This is the part of my code that I need help with:

```
with open('integration.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',', dialect='excel')
    writer.writerows(w for w in foundInstances)
```

For whatever reason, it seems that the delimiter is being ignored. When I open the file in Excel, each cell has one list. Using the old example, each cell would have "Google, http://google.com". I want Google in the first column and http://google.com in the second. So basically "Google" and "http://google.com", and then below that "BBC" and "http://bbc.co.uk". Is this possible?

Within my code, foundInstances is the list in which all the items are contained. As a whole, the script works fine, but I cannot seem to get this last step. I've done a lot of looking around within stackoverflow and the rest of the Internet, but I haven't found anything that has helped me with this last step.

Any advice is greatly appreciated. If you need more information, I'd be happy to provide you with it.

Thanks!

Comment: What does the file actually look like if you open it in a text editor?  Is it possible the file is correct but Excel is not interpreting it correctly?

Comment: Just fyi, to format a block of code correctly, just enter it like you normally do, select it and then click the `{}` button. That will indent everything by another 4 spaces which will make it a code block.

Comment: @BrenBarn Within a text editor, the file appears identically: "list1 item1, list1 item2", etc. It occurred to me that what you've suggested may be the case, but I assumed it was more likely I had done something wrong in the code.

Comment: Your delimiter appears to be `  `

Comment: @hd1 Wouldn't delimiter=',' set the delimiter to be a comma?

Comment: Can you provide a complete code example including example data that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: If something is surrounded by `"` then it means that it should be interpreted as one cell. So it only writes a single value `list1 item1, list1 item2` in the row, where the comma is part of the value. That sounds as if your original list has wrong format.

Comment: @poke That's what I was afraid of, but I've run out of ideas for fixing it.

Comment: Yes @CreativeName, but your sample is space-delimited, not comma-delimited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code on pastebin, the problem is here:

```
foundInstances.append(['http://' + str(num) + 'endofsite' + ', ' + desc])
```

Here, for each row in your data, you create one string that *already has* a comma in it.  That is not what you need for the `csv` module.  The CSV module *makes* comma-delimited strings out of your data.  You need to give it the data as a simple list of items `[col1, col2, col3]`.  What you are doing is `["col1, col2, col3"]`, which already has packed the data into a string.  Try this:

```
foundInstances.append(['http://' + str(num) + 'endofsite', desc])
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tested the code you posted with

```
foundInstances = [[1,2],[3,4]]
```

and it worked fine. It definitely produces the output csv in the format

```
1,2
3,4
```

So I assume that your `foundInstances` has the wrong format. If you construct the variable in a complex manner, you could try to add

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

before the actual variable usage in the csv code. This lets you inspect the variable at runtime with the python debugger. See the [Python Debugger Reference](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) for usage details.

As a side note, according to the [PEP-8 Style Guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the name of the variable should be `found_instances` in Python.

Comment: Thank you for the help. So when you do this, you get the 1 and the 2 in different cells within Excel?

Comment: It depends on how you get the file into Excel. If you just open it as a file, "1,2" are shown in one column as Excel just interprets the file as plain text. You have to use the data import function in Excel to read it as CSV. Which Excel version do you have? For my version (Excel 2012 for Mac), use File->Import->CSV. You can set set up e.g. the delimiters via a wizard.

Comment: I should have known that. Thank you - I guess I'll look around in Excel for a way to work with this.

Comment: @sebastian_oe:  -1.  Incorrect.  Excel correctly parses a file written in Excel dialect with csvwriter provided the file has a `.csv` extension.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: Well, my Excel version didn't. The csv file I wrote (with the provided code) wasn't even recognized as a valid "Excel file" in the regular open dialog. The file has a csv extension. It's a pity that you downvoted my answer (which has nothing to do with Excel) for a comment that just describes the behavior of the software I'm using.

Comment: @sebastian_oe: Yes, *with the provided code*.  The provided code has rows with no delimeter because he passed single item rows to the csv writer.  Admittedly, there are commas in the data file, but the csvwriter *properly* quoted those fields, which is *properly* interpreted by excel as indicating it is all one field.